# How to use Stimulus to fix "Cookies is not defined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, stimulusjs

I have a Rails v5.2.4 application using Ruby 2.5.3 and using the Stimulus 1.1.1 framework. I have some cookies set in my Rails controller and accessing  them from the Stimulus controller, but when I load the page for the first time I got:

```
ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined
    at Controller.connect (summary_controller.js:92)
    at Context.connect (context.js:23)
```

But when I reload the same page, I get the cookie value and everything works fine. I am not using any gem to handle cookies.

My stimulusjs method with corresponding line numbers is:

```
91  connect(){
92    var tech_and_monitor = Cookies.get('tech_and_monitor');
93    var tech_only = Cookies.get('tech_only');
95    var manager_only = Cookies.get('manager_only');
96    }
```

On the first load, when I used the live expression on browser `Cookies.get('tech_and_monitor');` I got the cookie value.

I don't understand the reason why I am not getting a reference to Cookies on first load and getting it on second?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the thing that thing responsible for not loading the JavaScript in Rails application is [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks). So I disable Turbolinks in the button where it is called from and JavaScript is loaded on first time too.

```
 <%= link_to "More Page", more_page_path, data:{turbolinks: false}, class: "nav-item nav-link"%>
```